# Fast way to create functions out of C code

Tags: c, function

I am working on a project and I have a C program where the code is over 3000 lines and takes lots of time to complete. I need to divide it into functions to get a faster result.

Is there a fast way or something or some way around I can use to help me make functions out a long C code?
Or will I have to go through the code doing all the functions manually?

For example this bit of code and lots and lots like it.

```
addr_len = sizeof their_addr;
if ((numbytes = recvfrom(sockfd, ubuf, 6 , 0,(struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &addr_len)) == -1) 
{
    perror("recvfrom");
    //exit(1);
}

inet_ntop(their_addr.ss_family,get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&their_addr),s, sizeof s);

//printf("listener: packet is %d bytes long\n", numbytes);

ubuf[numbytes] = '\0';
printf("listener: packet contains \"%s\"\n", ubuf);
```

Comment: 3000 lines isn't that long.  How long does it take to compile?

Comment: You can split large functions into smaller ones, if it helps readability or reuse. You can also profile and optimise slow code. The're not the same procedure.

Comment: split your code to function will not result an execution faster. it's the opposite if you split your code to function you will get execution slower. you will get your code more structured that's the goal

Comment: what do you mean by "lots of time to complete" ? Do you mean it takes a long time to compile?

Answer (score 2):

So far as my knowledge is concerned, there is no automated way to achieve this. You need to do this manually.

Answer (score 2):

3000 lines is not a lot of code...but it is a lot of code for a single function. While this probably will not have an effect on performance you should split your code for readability/maintenance and to avoid duplicate code.

If you think your code is taking too long profile it to see what is taking time but note that ,for instance, in the example you posted, you use recvfrom which can be a blocking function (nothing wrong with this but if you need to wait for incoming data your program will obviously take as long as it is needed for that data to arrive).

Comment: yes i am aware of the recvfrom but it is recieving at very high rate so makes no problem , i am actually working on 0.02 as max time spent to complete the loop which runs through the whole program even though i need to call some function at specific times and not all of the code is usefull all the time

Comment: note that there are tools such as [simian](http://www.harukizaemon.com/simian/index.html) and [atomiq](http://www.getatomiq.com/) which can help with finding similar code.